# TinyMCE windowManager.open() secure PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, file-upload, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE's `activeEditor.windowManager.open()` method to implement my own file browser. It opens a PHP script that does the file uploads/browser.

My concern is that anyone looking at the JavaScript will know the URL to my script and be able to open it in any browser window. I wouldn't want that because only admins to my web app should be able to upload or manage/delete stuff.

I have tried checking for `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` in my file browser script, but I think this is not foolproof.

Any ideas how this can be made more secure?

Comment: You can modify the .htaccess file to redirect users trying to acces your folder/file.

Comment: @iWumbo Thanks, but could you explain more?